# Calculate difference in cost based on combined query results

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

i have a table in Power BI that is the result of a combined query (3 tables), which means i have a column with 3 different project IDs (4010 = current project, 3844 = previous month's project, 3653 = baseline)

i have another column called "actual cost" and what i would like to do is add a calculated column that calculates for each row the difference between the actual cost in ID 4010 vs ID 3844, based on the denominator activity ID or name.

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Can you share example, data & screenshots?

Comment: Take a step back and explain the problem to us as if we've never seen your report ... because we actually haven't. And please share your sample data in copyable text format.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer a *Measure* in such situations. A *Calculated Column* is less flexible and more overhead. However, since that it was you asked for:

```
=
VAR ThisActivityID = Table1[activity ID]
VAR ActualCost4010 =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( Table1[actual cost] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( Table1 ),
            Table1[activity ID] = ThisActivityID
                && Table1[project ID] = 4010
        )
    )
VAR ActualCost3844 =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( Table1[actual cost] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( Table1 ),
            Table1[activity ID] = ThisActivityID
                && Table1[project ID] = 3844
        )
    )
RETURN
    ActualCost4010 - ActualCost3844
```